# OAuth2 "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-error://chromewebdata/#buttons"

Tags: javascript, redirect, strava

I am performing OAuth2 authentication with Strava API in Javascript for a web application written in HTML5. The authentication follows the Authorization Code Grant Flow. A first step is getting the user's permission and Access Code. Therefore I redirect the user to Strava EndPoint with the necessary parameters in the url.

```
var url = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize";
var params ="client_id=*****&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&scope=activity:write";
var request_url = url +"?"+ params;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

window.location.replace(url+"?"+params);
```

I arrive at the Strava Endpoint and then give my consent for using my data. Then I am then redirected to the application, but receive an error...

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   chrome-error://chromewebdata/#buttons

Any idea what can be wrong?